# Replace placeholder in graphql ignores enums and stringifies

Tags: graphql, karate

I'm reading a graphql query and store it in a variable, afterwards I do a replace of a variable in the stored graphql. The replacement is stringified, although there is an enum in.

```
query() {
  blabla(
    varToReplace: < varToReplace >
    queryOptions: {}
  ) {
    boemba {
      id
      )
    }
  }
}
```

My scenario part for reading in looks like this

```
...
  Given def query = read(karate.properties['user.dir'] + myGraphQL)
  *replace query. varToReplace = [{value: "boemba", matching: ONLY}]
...
```

But the actual query executed doesn't include ONLY in the matching key of the object, but "ONLY" which is the stringified value.

```
query() {
  blabla(
    varToReplace: [{"value":"boemba", "matching":"ONLY"}]
  ) {
    boemba {
      id
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the value replaced completely similar to the provided value, not having it all stringified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` keyword deals with pure strings and is not Java or JS type aware. So try this (note the single-quotes):

```
* replace query.varToReplace = '[{ value: "boemba", matching: ONLY }]'
```

Note that you can write your own JS utility function (or even Java) if the built-in `replace` does not work for you.